# Xcode Storyboard Tableview Cell of style "Subtitle" align to top

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, tableview

I'm looking for a way to align a table cell of style "Subtitle" to the top.
The cell includes a title and a description label (automatically). When the description contains text for 3 rows, the title label sticks to the top of the view. But when there are only 1 or 2 lines of text for instance in the description label, the title label is basically vertically centered in the view.

Is there a setting in the Interface Builder to align this custom cell type to the top of the cell view?

Thanks and regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, and if you need this amount of control, you should just subclass UITableViewCell and make it exactly like you want it. It's not very difficult to do and really takes all of guess work out of it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I ended up using a custom style and draw it myself. Just wondered why this can't be performed in an easy way.

Comment: Likely, their implementation just has custom code that handles for text larger than a particular size/number of lines. You could always "fake it" by putting in line breaks to mimic 3 rows (or maybe more).